# Why Android GCM RegistrationID not receive in Device?

Tags: android, emulation, google-cloud-messaging

I have developed an app which will send notifications to the registered Android Devices.

For this I need to register Device with Google Cloud Messaging Service. This will give me RegistrationId.

It received registrationId in Emulator but not in Device.

What could be the reason ?

```
//on MainActivity.java
//This code i am calling in onCreate()
//---------------------------------------
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(getBaseContext());

        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(getBaseContext());

        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("dotsandcoms.android.siteuplitenew.DISPLAY_MESSAGE"));

        regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(getBaseContext());

        if (regId.equals("")) {

            GCMRegistrar.register(getBaseContext(), "677416186780");

        } else {

            Log.v("siddharth", "Already registered");

            System.out.println("Registration ID : " + regId);

        }
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("message");

        System.out.println(newMessage + "\n");

    }
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
//This is the GCMIntentService code
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

@Override
protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "Error = " + arg1.toString());
}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String message = arg1.getStringExtra("message");
    generateNotification(arg0, message);
}

@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + arg1.toString());
    System.out.println("Registration ID : " + arg1.toString());
}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "on unregId = " + arg1.toString());
}

private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.icon;

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    // set intent so it does not start a new activity

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Comment: very massive. Please edit your question and format code.

Comment: Dude,your code is not readable,Please improve formatting of your question

Comment: To receive registration ID on your device ,your device need to be connected to Open Internet.

Comment: @Nargis I am able to receive id in emulator but not in device.

Comment: @Jaimin check if your device is connected to Internet/network

Comment: More over you can check tag:gcm logs to see what is going on

Comment: @Nargis Yes the device is connected to internet. Will check in log.

Comment: @Nargis Aftter checking Log i found error in the log. Is this the reason for not receiving ID ?  

_07-11 13:54:05.476: E/GCMRegistrar(16539): internal error: retry receiver class not set yet
07-11 13:54:05.476: V/GCMRegistrar(16539): Registering receiver
**07-11 13:54:05.477: D/GCMBaseIntentService(16539): handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, unregistered = null**
07-11 13:54:05.477: D/GCMBaseIntentService(16539): Registration error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE_

Comment: Yes ,this is the reason Registration error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, I have seen this coming when no network was available in  my device

Comment: Hi, I checked. Device is connected with internet. Also, I am checking for internet connection on application start. If no internet then application will not proceeds.

Comment: Yes, It was internet connectivity issue. Device wifi switch off regularly. Its working now.

Comment: @JaiminPatel: please post the solution as an answer otherwise delete the post. Thanks